# ClassNotFoundException but I can find this class in classes.dex

Tags: android, maven, jackson, dex, android-instrumentation

I have **two** projects:

- one is my android library project (com.my.lib),
- one is a test project to test the library project (com.my.lib.test).

In the test project, there is a test class which tests the corresponding class in library project which imports & uses `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory` class.

In test project, I have added dependency in maven build :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The **AndroidManifest.xml** of test project is like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.my.lib.test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.2" >
  <instrumentation
      android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
      android:targetPackage="com.my.lib" />

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

  <application>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

when I run **instrumentation** test, my tests are executed, but when executing that particular test class, I always get the following runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.my.lib.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.my.lib-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.lib.test-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.my.lib-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-06 18:06:08.041 24082 24998 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-06 18:06:08.041 24082 24998 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
```

So, the above log complains that it **couldn't find** `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory` class on those paths.

**BUT,** when I unzip my test project's APK file (`MyLibTest.apk`), and check the content of **classes.dex** by using Android SDK provided **dexdump** tool,
**I see the** `org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory` **is there!**

here is the command and output:

```
dexdump classes.dex | grep 'org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory'

      type          : 'Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;'
      type          : 'Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;'
```

Why I get `ClassNotFoundException` though I can find this class in **classes.dex** of test project's APK file?

**=== UPDATE ===**

Since the error log shows it tries to find from path "/data/app/com.my.lib.test-2/base.apk"

So, I also tried to download that base.apk, and check what is there by:

1. download it with adb tool

   adb pull /data/app/com.my.lib.test-2/base.apk
2. unzip base.api & I get the classes.dex from it
3. check the content of classes.dex by run command `dexdump classes.dex` , output is:

[image]

Does it mean `codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory` is only accessed but not included?

Comment: Can you confirm you're not facing the problem described here?  http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Please tell which version of java target and android build tools do you use? PS: it means that your classes byte code has link to `jackson` classes byte code but the last was not compiled for some reason. I had this problem when I tried to include library written in Java 1.7 to project that was compiled by 1.6.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same problem.